# How to get a single WSDL file in "WCF routing service" for all the services behind the routing service?

Tags: wcf, wsdl

is this possible to get a single WSDL file in "WCF routing service"(hosted on IIS) for all the services behind the routing service?

Using this WSDL file, All Clients can directly consume it and generate proxy class that actually point to router service rather than individual services.

Thanks.